# ec2 storage maxed out by /var/spool/mqueue-client how to stop and remove files

Tags: ubuntu

So one of my instances is maxing it's storage pretty hard:

```
sudo du -h --max-depth=1 /var/spool
4.0K    /var/spool/mqueue
28K     /var/spool/cron
4.0K    /var/spool/rsyslog
152G    /var/spool/mqueue-client
152G    /var/spool
```

I use sendgrid for email on the site, this server shouldn't need mail capacity at all. Can I disable this somehow and nuke all the files that are filling it up so bad?